# Can I get the extend-er class' name in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to load files depending on the name of the class that extends my base class. Given the following classes:

```
class LoaderBase {
   var data: String = stuff(extender.getClass().getName()+".json")
}

class FooBar extends LoaderBase {
    var something: String = data
}
```

Is it possible without manually passing the used class' name to the base class?

Comment: What is *"**it**"* in *"Is **it** possible"*? If you call `data` on `new FooBar`, you get `FooBar.json`. What did you expect to get instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `this` can get the current **Instance** class, so you can do it like:

```
var data: String = this.getClass.getSimpleName
```

Comment: I didn't expect it to be so simple!